# How can the backend know if the request is coming from the same machine the firebase user logged in on?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a little unclear on part of the Firebase auth flow.

I'm using the prebuilt ui to sign a user in on the web frontend, and after that's completed I'm using this, partially pseudo-coded:

```
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
    const idToken = await authResult.user.getIdToken();
    setIdTokenAsCookie(idToken);
    reloadPage();
}
```

The idea is that the user has signed in, so I set the idToken as a cookie and refresh the page. The backend gets the idToken from the cookie, then checks Firebase to validate the idToken there, and returns the logged-in page with user-specific data.

But....how does the backend know that this request came from the machine the user logged-in on? Couldn't an attacker on another computer send a request with a brute-force guessed idtoken and thus gain access? Is it a matter of rate-limiting the endpoint on my backend to prevent them finding a valid idtoken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But....how does the backend know that this request came from the machine the user logged-in on?

It doesn't, and that's not required.

> Couldn't an attacker on another computer send a request with a brute-force guessed idtoken and thus gain access?

That is astronomically unlikely to happen.  If this is what you're worried about, you're worried about things that are normally considered cryptographically secure. The idToken you get from Auth is a JWT. [Read more about that.](https://jwt.io/)

> Is it a matter of rate-limiting the endpoint on my backend to prevent them finding a valid idtoken?

I would consider this a waste of effort.

Comment: Understood. So the flow I've described is a valid firebase auth flow, then? I was concerned I was missing something.

Comment: If you're verifying the token with the Firebase Admin SDK on your backend, you don't have much to worry about.